# UILabel value not updating inside Parse block

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, event-dispatch-thread

I have the following code:

```
var gaugeView1 = CHCircleGaugeView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 280))
self.mainGaugeView.addSubview(gaugeView1)
gaugeView1.setTitleValue("TODAY", hideLabel: false);

var query = PFQuery(className: "Values")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) in
    if let valObjects = objects as? [PFObject] {
        for val in valObjects {
            if let average = val.objectForKey("AVERAGE") as? Double {
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    gaugeView1.setValue(average, hideLabel: false, animated: true)
                })
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The problem is that the `gaugeView1.setValue()` is not actually updating the value.

Originally I didn't have it running on the main thread and then added in the `dispatch_sync()` unfortunately that hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: I guess you've already double-checked that `dispatch_sync` is indeed getting called? Minor suggestion: try to add a `gaugeView1.setNeedsDisplay()` immediately after the value update?

Comment: try dispatch_async instead of  dispatch_sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `dispatch_async` instead of `dispatch_sync`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
  gaugeView1.setValue(average, hideLabel: false, animated: true)
})
```